# LINQ calling a method inside Select passing as parameter the selected item

Tags: c#, linq

I've a LINQ statement where inside the *Select* I need to call a method that has as parameter the item selected in the query.

Here's an example:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo> {....};

float GetPrice(Foo) {....}

var query = foos
  .Where(x => x.ID == 1)
  .Select(x => new
  {
    aaa = GetPrice(????)
  });
```

How can I specify the selected Foo in the call to GetPrice(????) ?

Comment: `GetPrice(x)`    .

Comment: It is the name you gave it in your lambda: `x`.

Comment: Do you have any memory of writing the `Where` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` within your `Select()` statement is going to represent a `Foo` object, since you are querying from a `List<Foo>`, so you should just be able to pass in `x` to your `GetPrice()` method :

```
aaa = GetPrice(x)
```

So your entire code would look something like this :

```
var query = foos.Where(x => x.ID == 1)
                .Select(x => new {
                      aaa = GetPrice(x)
                });
```

Comment: Since the signature of `GetPrice` is `float GetPrice(Foo)` you actually can use the method group name instead of the lambda: `foos.Where(...).Select(GetPrice);`

Comment: @Rion Williams  You're right. Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Good point René, I often forget about the method group syntax or simply don't use it as much as I should (and I don't frequently map a single property too often).

Comment: @RenéVogt you're right but I need to use the *new* keyword because I need to call some other methods that use the same parameter type. What I shown was just a simple snippet. Thank you.

Comment: GetPrice will replace a `x => GetPrice(x)`. It will not properly replace `x => new {aaa = GetProce(x)}`

Comment: why I can't mark the answer as accepted before 5 minutes if I've tested the answer and it's right?

Comment: It's just a measure to make sure that the OP considers other posts that might come in within a reasonable period of time.